# DataFrame with Nan values into matrix (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, nan

Is there a way to convert a panda.Dataframe composed by numpy.float64 and Nan values into a matrix that has some fixed values instead of nan values?

It is my first question and i'm starting to use python then sorry if it isn't an intelligent question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `df.fillna(value)` or `df.replace(np.nan, value)`